# Ruby Rack Redirect Incoming Domain Requests to Subfolder

Tags: ruby, redirect, dns, jekyll, rack

So I'm trying to use one Heroku instance for multiple sites. The site code itself is using jekyll so it's just a ton of static pages in subfolders.

Anyways, I want to map domain.com to heroku_instance.com/sub_folder. 
So:

- domain.com => heroku_instance.com/domain.com
- domain.com/blog => heroku_instance.com/domain.com/blog
- domain2.com => heroku_instance.com/domain2.com
- domain2.com/blog => heroku_instance.com/domain2.com/blog

Comment: I am not sure if Heroku is the right answer for static web sites. IMHO something like GitHub Pages or AWS S3 would be a better solution.

Comment: So I could just follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts this on AWS and build my Jekyll sites there. Does that sound correct?